# Does google maps use fusedlocationproviderclient?? if yes how is google maps faster than if i use it in my location logger app

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am building a location longing app, right now i'm using **fusedlocationproviderclient** which is recommended in the google docs.
so when i press my location log button it requests for location updates and in the location listener when i get the location results i remove location updates i did this to save battery (because **fusedlocationproviderclient** does not have any method to request only a single location update).
The problem is

-(1) that when i press the button my loction gets logged but it takes time sometimes >30s but google maps does not take so much time why??

-(2) i read some on some blog that google maps uses ***network provider*** or ***wifi*** or ***bluetooth*** to get first a rough location, but should't **fusedlocationproviderclient** also use all of the method.

-(3) So the bottom question is does google maps use **fusedlocationproviderclient** or not and if yes how does it implement it to get such fast results

Comment: why would google hand you all the keys to their solution? maps is still a service they would rather you use than roll your own solution. google maps initally uses a combination of cell tower data and wifi access point data that they have created a database of to get a rough location and then uses fusedlocationprovider's data to get a more accurate location. you can implement this yourself too by getting cell tower data or by making it so your app reports celltower/wifi access point data back to you and link the gps coordinates to them.

Comment: Ahh i thought that fusedlocationproviderclient does all that internally because of the name.thanks tho

Comment: i don't even use it personally coz of the google play services requirement, your app won't work on any phone that doesn't have play(most of china, some cheap chinese phones)